# Error Exporting SQL to CSV - Pipeline

Tags: sql, excel, csv, export

Very new to coding / Powershell, but I am very close on my project. Trying to automate connecting to my SQL DB and export to CSV (or excel if possible). I am successfully connecting to the database and getting accurate information but I can't seem to get the data to export to the file. Here is my code:

```
$DBServer = "E2\E2SQL"
$databasename = "****"
$UID = "sa"
$pass = "*****"
$Connection = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection #Set new object to connect to sql database
$Connection.ConnectionString ="server=$DBServer;database=$databasename;User Id=$UID;password=$pass;trusted_connection=False" # Connectiongstring setting for local machine database with window authentication
Write-host "Connection Information:"  -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor black
$Connection #List connection information


### Connect to Database and Run Query

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand #setting object to use sql commands

$SqlQuery = @"

SELECT JobNo FROM Online

"@

$Connection.open()
Write-host "Connection to database successful." -foregroundcolor green -backgroundcolor black
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$SqlCmd.Connection = $Connection
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$Connection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0]
export-csv -path "C:\Users\BOB\Desktop\TEST.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

When I run the code, the correct information shows! However, I get a popup that says "cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1 - Supply values for the following parameters: InputObject" I've been trying to figure this out but have been unsuccessful. Any idea what this error is or how to fix it? How to get the data to write to my CSV (or excel if possible)?
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way of doing it:

```
$output ="C:\Users\BOB\Desktop\TEST.csv"   
$DBServer = "E2\E2SQL"
$databasename = "****"
$UID = "sa"
$pass = "*****"
$SqlQuery = @"SELECT JobNo FROM Online"@


invoke-sqlCmd -serverinstance @DBServer -database $databasename 
      -Username $UID -Password $pass -Query $SqlQuery |  Export-Csv $output
```